# WP conditional site logo and header block

Tags: conditional-content

i have a customer who had 3 different sites and they wanted to bring all 3 sites under one umbrella site. however, each of the companies have different logos. when i define a logo for the site, it shows all-tru the site.

what i need is a particular logo for each of the sites;

main (landing) site -> logo-main.png
art site -> logo-art.png
print site -> logo-print.png

i am not a coder, just a designer so if i am to do some php editing, please be as specific as possbile.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you'll use [multisite](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/) and for adding logo you just need to go to individual site and enable option to add logo(will be available in the theme you are using).

Next step is to alter header.php from your theme and add following lines of code where you have  `the_custom_logo();`
TO:

```
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );   //where `$blog_id` is current site id
the_custom_logo();
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. there has been some misunderstanding probably due to my wording of my issue;

it will not be a multi-site. if it were, there would be multiple wp installations and hence, there wouldnt be any logo/header issue.

its 3 sites gathered under 1 site. so its like;

homepage     --> main landing page (nothing much on it accept introductions etc)
homepage - art   --> main page for arts and collections
homepage - print  --> main page for printed stuff

Comment: they share the same wp database and woocommerce and addons. i used conditional menu addon for

homepage  (and related pages such as about1, contact1)
homepage - arts (and related pages such as about2, contact2, artsubpages)
homepage - prints (and related pages such as about3, contact3, printsubpages)

i just need something similar in logic, conditional header or logo.

Comment: If that is the case than you'll need to use same script in header.php which u used for menu. So basically u can try page id in header.php with if...else use logo of your choice